# Removing rows based on certain criteria in a column number

Tags: r

I have a csv file with no column or row names and my first column is for the year (see example below). I would like to remove all rows where the value in column 1 is not 2015. I know this would normally be a very straight-forward question, but all of the code I would normally use for this would require me to specify a column name.  Is there a way I can do this by specifying the column number in the code instead?

```
 2015   11   3   -120   -160
 2015   11   4   -130   -198
 2015   11   5   -128   -176
 2000    1   1   -154   -123
 2015   11   6   -132   -128
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We read the dataset with `header=FALSE` so that the columns will be named with default column names i.e. 'V1', 'V2', etc...  Then, we subset the rows by using the logical condition on the first column.

```
df1 <- read.csv('yourfile.csv', header=FALSE)
df1[df1[,1]!=2015,]
```